# Show all genres separated by "," (Array to string conversion)

Tags: php, laravel

This dump:

```
dd($moviesInformation['movies']['data'][1]['genres']);
```

show all genres for each movie returned like this:

```
^ array:2 [▼
  "data" => array:32 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▶]
    1 => array:3 [▶]
    2 => array:3 [▼
      "id" => 446
      "genre" => array:1 [▼
        "label" => "Comedy"
      ]
      "on_request" => 1
    ]
    3 => array:3 [▶]
    4 => array:3 [▶]
    5 => array:3 [▶]
```

And I want to, based on this, have an output with all genres separated by ",", like this:

```
'result' => [Comedy, Action, etc],
```

However doing like this:

```
collect($moviesInformation['movies']['data'])->map(function ($movie) {
            return [
                'result' => implode(',', $movie['genres'])
            ];
        });
```

Im getting "`Array to string conversion`". Do you know how to properly achieve that?

Comment: Does `'result' => implode(',', array_map(function($genre) { return $genre['label']; }, $movie['genres']))` work?

Comment: Thanks but it shows Undefined array key "label".

Comment: Could you please provide `var_dump($moviesInformation['movies']['data'][1])` and not `dd()`

Comment: Its like this "array(2) { ["data"]=> array(32) { [0]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> int(64) ["name"]=> array(1) { ["label"]=> string(10) "Comedy" } ["on_request"]=> int(1) } [1]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> int(65) ["name"]=> array(1) { ["label"]=> string(5) "Action" } ["on_request"]=> int(1) } [2]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> int(446) ["name"]=> array(1) { ["label"]=> string(23) "Documentary" } ["on_request"]=> int(1) } [3]=> array(3) {
". Thanks!

Comment: No I mean can you put the whole thing in your question so I can copy and paste. I have a function that can convert the var_dumped data into an array I can use for testing. Or better yet, could you please do `var_export` instead and put in your question.

Comment: The structure with var_export is like this: array ( 'data' => array ( 0 => array ( 'id' => 64, 'name' => array ( 'label' => 'Comedy', ), 'on_request' => 1, ), 1 => array ( 'id' => 65, 'name' => array ( 'label' => 'Action', ), 'on_request' => 1, ), 2 => array ( 'id' => 446, 'name' => array ( 'label' => 'Documentary', ), 'on_request' => 1, ), 3 => array (...), some for the other array items.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244105/discussion-between-bernard-and-jacob-mulquin).